# Why we need toJSON when comparing to two components equality?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I write component which convert text with \n line break to html paragraph

Text.js

```
const Text = props => ((
  <div>
    { props.paragraph.split('\n').map((line, index) => {
      if (line.length === 0) return;
      return <p key={index}>{ line }</p>;
    })}
  </div>
)
);
```

When I want to compare to Components, there is error if I call it without `toJSON` to rendered Component. (Even though result is the same when I check with toMatchSnapshot())

Text.spec.js

```
it('ignores \\n at last', () => {
  const paragraphA = 'aa\nbbb\n';
  const paragraphB = 'aa\nbbb';
  const cA = renderer.create(<Text paragraph={paragraphA} />);
  const cB = renderer.create(<Text paragraph={paragraphB} />);
  expect(cA).toEqual(cB); // NG
  expect(cA.toJSON()).toEqual(cB.toJSON()); // OK
});
```

jest tells Difference as below

> Compared values serialize to the same structure.
>   Printing internal object structure without calling `toJSON` instead.

I google it but could not find any clue about toJSON

- Why do we need `toJSON` here?
- what `toJSON` do generally?
- Where can I find reference about toJSON?

Env

react: 16.1
jest-cli": "^21.2.1"

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior):

> **toJSON behavior**
>
> If an object being stringified has a property named `toJSON` whose value is a function, then the `toJSON` method customizes JSON stringification behavior: instead of the object being serialized, the value returned by the `toJSON` method when called will be serialized.

Examples:

```js
//without toJSON
const a = {
  b: 1
};
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(a)
);
```

```js
//with toJSON
const a = {
  b: 1,
  toJSON: () => ({
    c: 100
  })
};
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(a)
);
```

I think you should compare *cA.toJSON()* instead of raw function *cA.toJSON*.

Why it's necessary? When you compare objects (including arrays and functions), they are compared by referrence instead of value. React component has complex structure (e.g. references to another components as properties), so trying to stringify it instead of its .toJSON() (which returns safe object) would throw an error. For example, it wouldn't work if you have custom function for parsing JSON which don't checks for .toJSON method.

Comment: Thanks for detail comment! 

I don't know if It is necessary yet. However I encountered following error without toJSON. 

>     -         "_debugID": 17,
>     +         "_debugID": 9,

Because of this, I thought I cannot just compare two components.

Then I wen to jest docs. Almost everytime it renders component for test with calling toJSON() method.  So I thought this can solve my problem, and actually it seems like solving. I found no error with `npm test`

Could you please tell me if I have any misunderstanding about this thinking?

Comment: @KanUchida Yes, you're right. Jasmine test works with objects, but doesn't work with referrences e.g. to functions, even if they have same structure (but are allocated in other place in memory). Always call .toJSON() method on React components to get safe object literal - without these referrences.

Comment: I got it !Thanks a lot! I understand deeply thanks to you :D